# How to save byte[] to varbinary(64) field in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have

```
byte[] a = HashEncrypt("a");
```

with

```
public byte[] HashEncrypt(string password)
{
    SHA512Managed sha = new SHA512Managed();
    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password));
    return hash;
}
```

I want to save `byte[] a` to my database. My database field is a `varbinary(64)`. I'm using SQL Server 2008. I want to know the insert query with C# code.

I am using ADO.NET

Comment: how are you doing your db access?  Can you show how you are trying to do the insert?

Comment: What data access framework are you using? ADO.NET? LINQ-to-SQL? Entity Framework? NHibernate? Something else...?

Comment: and minor nit, but it's spelled Encrypt with a y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure how you're doing this as pointed out in the comments under your question, but I've added a `byte[]` to my db table by using a `SqlParamenter` inside of a `SqlCommand`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into binaryTable (example) values (@example)",connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@example",HashEncript("password"));
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: thanks really it's really helpful for me thanks again. LINQ-to-SQL? Entity Framework? NHibernate? will you tell me about them.If i want to use them how to .thanks again